# Code Improvement/Insight: Should I have approached these functions differently? Animations using Javascript

Tags: javascript, react.js

This code works as it is intended. What I seek is a feedback on the quality of my code. Where should I have written it differently or how should have I approached instead of the way that I have?

These functions will be moved to a separate file to be used on other pages as well. My goal is to have this code reusable as well.

I tried using `onMouseOver={ani.bind(this)}`

I've also tried `let element = ani()` but received undefined

`<img className="gPic" src={img['roofRepair1'].src} alt={img['roofRepair1'].alt} id="special" onMouseOver={ani} onMouseLeave={revani}/>`

```js
//Function anime: Anime.js

function ani(p){
    let element = p.target.id 
    anime({
        targets: '#'+ element,
        scale: 2,
    })
    return element;
}

function revani(p){
    let element = p.target.id 
    anime({
        targets:'#'+ element,
        scale: 1
    })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. This code is much to sketchy for us to give you proper advice. Ideally, you should press Control-M in the question editor to make a working demonstration. See [ask].

Comment: _My goal is to have this code reusable as well._ -> each attempt you tried so far failed _but received undefined_. Is the code really working as intended?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: The title might be better as Animations using JavaScript. The question would be better if you added an explanation of what the code is animating and provided some working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce this code down to one function by using [default arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument).

```
function ani(p, reverse=false){
    let element = p.target.id;
    let scale = 2;
    if (reverse)
        scale = 1;
    anime({
        targets: '#'+ element,
        scale: scale,
    })
    return element;
}
```

Also, don't forget your semicolons ;-P